# Underscore where: How to check for matching strings for case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using Underscore.js library to check for email address string inside my collection, if exists, like this:

```
var emailExists = this.model.get('emailmailCollection').where( {emailAddress:emailAddressValue});
```

It works perfectly for strings like **aa@a.com, etc.** but when I match emails like **Aa@a.com & aa@a.com,** it doesn't show it exists.

Is there a way to test for emails with case-insensitive in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) instead.

```
var emailExists = this.model.get('emailmailCollection').filter(function(email){
   return email.get('emailAddress').toUpperCase() === emailAddressValue.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are getting Aa@a.com, use the `.toLowerCase()` method on it and on your input. This way, all of your data is all lowercase.

For example:

`console.log("Hello WOrLD".toLowerCase())`

returns

`hello world`

this is a really amateurish way and probably won't work for you, but that's what I would try.